# What is the time Complexity of array initialization with filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, time-complexity

**Scenario 1:**

`Const array = [false, false, true, false, true].filter(Boolean)` // Time Complexity is 2n

**Scenario 2:**

```
const array = [];
if(false) array.push(true);
if(false) array.push(true);
if(true) array.push(true);
if(false) array.push(true);
if(true) array.push(true);
```

*For Scenario 2, Time complexity is n.*

---

So, my question is, Here is My assumption of time complexity for both scenarios right or wrong?

If I am wrong then please give me the description with the correct answer

and is there any way to do the program with O(n) complexity?

and if my assumption is correct then for scenario 2, the syntax looks bad like multiple times `if`
so is there any good way to correct the syntax?

---

Comment: As an aside, in theory O(2n) = O(n)

Comment: You've probably tried to generalise some case but ended up with an entirely useless case. You are trying to produce an array of variable length but all members are `true`. An "optimised" solution would drop the array and just give you a count. Because `[true, true, true]` can be much more succinctly be expressed as `3`. Yet that's not exactly *useful*. Moreover, where are these inputs coming from? If it's just hardcoded you don't need an algorithm for it - manually remove all `false` and you're done. Yet an `n` in the `O` notation suggests variability of the input.

Comment: These inputs are conditions-based, but here I have added the static to give you the example, actually, it is coming from the backend and need to check the permissions and falsy values

Comment: O(n) is better than O(2n). that's why I asked this question

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, O(n) is equal to O(2n). Indeed, both of your code snippets run in linear time, and are in O(n).

If you want to know which is faster, I suggest you benchmark the actual code.